# remove zeros between values of a list

Tags: python

I have a list of list and I want to remove zero values that are between numbers in each list. All my lists inside my list have same lenght.

For example:

`List1=[[0,1,0,2,3,0,0],[0,5,6,0,0,9,0]]`

desired output:

`list2=[[0,1,2,3,0,0],[0,5,6,9,0]]`

I was thinking about using indices to identify the first non zero value and last non zero value, but then I don't know how I can remove zeros between them.

Comment: Are all the numbers single digit?

Comment: no, it's just for the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, I think, with finding the first and last indices of nonzeroes and removing zeroes between them. Here's a function that does that:

```
def remove_enclosed_zeroes(lst):
    try:
        first_nonzero = next(
            i 
            for (i, e) in enumerate(lst) 
            if e != 0
        )
        last_nonzero = next(
            len(lst) - i - 1 
            for (i, e) in enumerate(reversed(lst)) 
            if e != 0
        )
    except StopIteration:
        return lst[:]
    return lst[:first_nonzero] + \
           [e for e in lst[first_nonzero:last_nonzero] if e != 0] + \
           lst[last_nonzero:]

list1 = [[0,1,0,2,3,0,0],[0,5,6,0,0,9,0]]
list2 = [remove_enclosed_zeroes(sublist) for sublist in list1]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0], [0, 5, 6, 9, 0]]
```

Comment: @Nick Thanks for pointing that out, I got the logic backwards for if `next()` gives a stopiteration. The only scenario in which it would do so is if the list is entirely zeroes, or empty, so I've fixed that bit of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @python_user I thought about this a bit more and came up with this simpler solution:

```py
def remove_internal_zeros(lst):
    return [v for i, v in enumerate(lst) if v or not any(lst[i+1:]) or not any(lst[:i])]
```

This works by passing any value from the original list which is either

1. not zero (`v`); or
2. zero and not preceded by a non-zero value (`not any(lst[:i])`); or
3. zero and not followed by a non-zero value (`not any(lst[i+1:])`)

It can also be written as a list comprehension:

```py
list2 = [[v for i, v in enumerate(lst) if v or not any(lst[:i]) or not any(lst[i+1:])] for lst in list1]
```

**Original Answer**

Here's another brute force approach, this pops all the zeros off either end of the list into `start` and `end` lists, then filters the balance of the list for non-zero values:

```py
def remove_internal_zeros(l):
    start_zeros = []
    # get starting zeros
    v = l.pop(0)
    while v == 0 and len(l) > 0:
        start_zeros.append(0)
        v = l.pop(0)
    if len(l) == 0:
        return start_zeros + [v]
    l = [v] + l
    # get ending zeros
    end_zeros = []
    v = l.pop()
    while v == 0 and len(l) > 0:
        end_zeros.append(0)
        v = l.pop()
    # filter balance of list
    if len(l) == 0:
        return start_zeros + [v] + end_zeros
    return start_zeros + list(filter(bool, l)) + [v] + end_zeros

print(remove_internal_zeros([0,1,0,2,3,0,0]))
print(remove_internal_zeros([0,5,6,0,0,9,0]))
print(remove_internal_zeros([0,0]))
print(remove_internal_zeros([0,5,0]))
```

Output:

```py
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 5, 6, 9, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 5, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to be done with brute force.

```
new = []
for sub in List1:
    # Find last non-zero.
    for j in range(len(sub)):
        if sub[-1-j]:
            lastnonzero = len(sub)-j
            break
    print(j)
    newsub = []
    firstnonzero = False
    for i,j in enumerate(sub):
        if j:
            firstnonzero = True
            newsub.append(j)
        elif i >= lastnonzero or not firstnonzero:
            newsub.append(j)
    new.append(newsub)

print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, remove all 0 between numbers in each list.:

```
list1=[[0,1,0,2,3,0,0],[0,5,6,0,0,9,0]]

rowIndex=len(list1)  # count of rows
colIndex=len(list1[0])   # count of columns

for i in range(0, rowIndex):
    noZeroFirstIndex = 1
    noZeroLastIndex = colIndex - 2
    for j in range(1, colIndex - 1):
        if(list1[i][j] != 0):
            noZeroFirstIndex = j
            break
            
    for j in range(colIndex -2, 0, -1):
        if(list1[i][j] != 0):
            noZeroLastIndex = j
            break
    
    for j in range(noZeroLastIndex, noZeroFirstIndex, -1):
        if(list1[i][j] == 0 ):
            del list1[i][j]
        
print(list1)
```

Result:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0], [0, 5, 6, 9, 0]]
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to remove all 0s

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a pretty straight-forward approach. Try this.

```
def removeInnerZeroes(list):
    listHold=[]
    listNew = []
    firstNonZeroFound = False
    for item in list:
        if item==0:
            if firstNonZeroFound:
                listHold.append(item)
            else:
                listNew.append(item)
        else:
            firstNonZeroFound=True
            listHold.clear()
            listNew.append(item)
    listNew.extend(listHold)
    return listNew


complexList = [[0,1,0,2,3,0,0],[0,5,6,0,0,9,0]]
print(complexList)
complexListNew = []
for listi in complexList:
    complexListNew.append(removeInnerZeroes(listi))
print(complexListNew)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to treat each sublist as 3 sections:

- Zeros at the front, if any
- Zeros at the end, if any
- Numbers in the middle from which zeros are to be purged

`itertools.takewhile` is handy for the front and end bits.

```
from itertools import takewhile
List1=[[0,1,0,2,3,0,0],[0,5,6,0,0,9,0]]

def purge_middle_zeros(numbers):
    is_zero = lambda x: x==0
    leading_zeros = list(takewhile(is_zero, numbers))
    n_lead = len(leading_zeros)
    trailing_zeros = list(takewhile(is_zero, reversed(numbers[n_lead:])))
    n_trail = len(trailing_zeros)
    mid_numbers = numbers[n_lead:-n_trail] if n_trail else numbers[n_lead:]
    mid_non_zeros = [x for x in mid_numbers if x]
    return leading_zeros + mid_non_zeros + trailing_zeros
    
list2 = [purge_middle_zeros(sub_list) for sub_list in List1]
list2
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0], [0, 5, 6, 9, 0]]
```

Other notes:

- the `lambda` function `is_zero` tells `takewhile` what the criteria are for continuing, in this case "keep taking while it's a zero"
- for the `mid_non_zeros` section the list comprehension `[x for.... ]` takes all the numbers except for the zeros (the `if x` at the end applies the filter)
- slicing notation to pick out the middle of the list, `numbers[from_start:-from_end]` with the negative `-from_end` meaning 'except for this many elements at the end'. The case where there are no trailing zeros requires a different slice expression, i.e. `numbers[from_start:]`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code out of curiosity, that is somewhat intuitive and mimics a "looking item-by-item" approach.

```
def remove_zeros_inbetween(list_):
    new_list = list_.copy()
    for j, l in enumerate(list_): # loop through the inner lists
        checking = False
        start = end = None
        i = 0
        deleted = 0
        while i < len(l): # loop through the values of an inner list
            if l[i] == 0: # ignore
                i += 1
                continue
            
            if l[i] != 0 and not checking: # non-zero value found
                checking = True # start checking for zeros
                start = i
            elif l[i] != 0 and checking: # if got here and checking, the finish checking
                checking = False
                end = i
                                        
            if start and end: # if both values have been set, i.e, different to None
                # delete values in-between
                new_list[j] = new_list[j][:(start+1-deleted)] + new_list[j][(end-deleted):] 
                deleted += end - start - 1
                
                if l[i] != 0: # for the case of two non-zero values
                    start = i
                    checking = True
                else:
                    i = end # ignore everything up to end
    
                end = None # restart check
            i += 1
            
    return new_list
        
>>> remove_zeros_inbetween([[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 5], [0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 9, 4]])
    [[0, 1, 2, 3, 5], [0, 5, 6, 9, 4]]

>>> remove_zeros_inbetween([[0, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0]]))
    [[0, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0]]

>>> remove_zeros_inbetween([[0, 0, 0, 0]]))
    [[0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You start by replacing 0 by "0" - which is not necessary. Secondly your filter call does not save the resulting list; try:

```
list1[i] = list(filter(lambda a: a !=0, list1[1:-1])) # changed indexing , I suppose this could work
```

Comment: How does this handle his requirement of keeping the leading and trailing 0s?

Comment: This only remove 0 but does not handle the first and last zeroes

Comment: make sure you understood the problem correctly and tested the given input personally.